# Slide-out menu does not display navigation links in section 2 of web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I've searched high and low to figure this one out. Basically, I've got a full screen slide-out menu on my website which displays links to 4 pages of the website (ie. Home, About, Where, and Help pages). It's the main navigation, which slides out from a hamburger menu icon. It works fine and dandy at the top of any page, but after smooth scrolling down to the second section of any page and clicking the fixed menu icon, the menu slides out only to display the navy blue background, without any of the links. It's as though the background extends down to section 2 but the links are stuck at the top. Any assistance would be AMAZING as this is for a uni assignment due in 2 weeks.

Here is a link to the current (draft) website: https://jessjonesgraphics.000webhostapp.com

Here is an image to show you what I mean specifically: [Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nFg7.png)

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the css of .slider-container .slider-parent to postion:fixed

The problem here is that its still sliding out with the links but since you are already scrolled down you are just getting the bottom blank blue of the slide out.

By switching the position from absolute to fixed no matter where the slider is pulled out on the page it will show the menu because its fixed on the viewport.

Comment: Also change the z-index of .up to 3 and the slider z-index to 4 as the up button is showing over the slide out

Comment: No on the .slider-container. Sorry should of specified on which class

Comment: Sorry, Mernlin, you're right! You have solved my problem! How easy... Can't thank you enough. Also, great tip about the z-index for the arrow button and slide out menu. LEGEND.

Comment: hahaha allsweet its always something simple you spend hours stressing about been there before. Good Luck on the assignment